# Adding multiple CheckBoxes for a map viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I've created a list of structs, each of which has a few properties. My intention is to use a basic 10x10 map to practice / learn to write A* Search Algorithms for a game I'm developing a tool for. I've got the map structure as basically an array of Tile objects, each of which has the following properties:

```
    public struct Tile
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int cost { get; set; }
        public bool walkable { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a struct for Nodes, though it's irrelevant to this question, really, I'll post it incase anyone has anything to shout at me about:

```
    public struct Node
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int cost { get; set; }
        public Tile parent { get; set; }
    }
```

My formload event looks something like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox[] chbs = new CheckBox[100];
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                Map = new Structs.Tile[100];
                Map[x + y].x = x;
                Map[x + y].y = y;
                Map[x + y].cost = 100;
                Map[x + y].walkable = true;
                //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(Map[x + y].x) + " : " + Convert.ToString(Map[x + y].y));
                if ( x == 5 )
                {
                    if (y == 4 | y == 5 | y == 6)
                    {
                        Map[x + y].walkable = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Structs.Tile tile in Map)
        {
            CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
            chb.Location = new Point(tile.x * 20, tile.y * 20);
            chb.Text = "";
            chbs[i] = chb;
            i++;
        }
        this.Controls.AddRange(chbs);
    }
```

And I've declared this before hand, to use globally through this class:

```
Structs.Tile[] Map;
```

The question is, why does this only add 2 check boxes? It appears to add them at approximately the right place for the one located at X: 0, Y: 0, X: 1, Y: 1, but no others are added? I've expanded the form to ridiculous sizes and still nothing. I'm utterly baffled by it.

Here is the result, with the multipliers set each to 2:

[image: Test program screenshot displaying the issue]

I believe I've set it up correctly, and I can't work out why it's not working. I could understand if the form was freezing but it's just not, and setting the values to something stupidly high (100+) doesn't make any difference. The offsets in WinForms suggest the multiplier would need to be approximately 12...

As usual, any advice is more than welcome. I'll try to answer some questions here soon, too, as I've learnt so much from you wonderful people!

Thanks!

Revised FormLoad:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ind = 0;
        CheckBox[] chbs = new CheckBox[100];
        Map = new Structs.Tile[100];
        for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < 11; y++)
            {
                Map[ind].x = x;
                Map[ind].y = y;
                Map[ind].cost = 100;
                Map[ind].walkable = true;
                //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(Map[x + y].x) + " : " + Convert.ToString(Map[x + y].y));
                if ( x == 5 )
                {
                    if (y == 4 | y == 5 | y == 6)
                    {
                        Map[ind].walkable = false;
                    }
                }
                ind++;
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Structs.Tile tile in Map)
        {
            CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
            chb.Location = new Point(tile.x * 12, tile.y * 12);
            chb.Text = "";
            chbs[i] = chb;
            i++;
        }
        this.Controls.AddRange(chbs);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried something new, adding an index to the while loops for setting X & Y, and it didn't seem to help, I'll edit it in now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I was resetting the array each time I entered the bloody loop. Gah, it's too late for this!

Thanks to all who looked / considered!